# Want to arrange css divs in a proper way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

Please, Please answer / help me.

I have three `div`s with CSS and it is generated dynamically.

And I call them `wincontainer`, `smalldiv` and `largediv`. `wincontainer` is a container of `smalldiv` and `largediv` as we can see in the image.

[image]

**properties of `div`s**

```
<!-- wincontainer -->
<ol class="wincontainer" style="width: 938px;float: left;border: 2px solid #CCC;"></ol>

<!-- smalldiv -->
<div id="smalldiv" style="
     width: 420px;
     margin: 10px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     font-size: 13px;    
     text-align: justify;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;    
     border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;    
     float: right;
     clear: right;"> </div>

<!-- largediv -->
<div id="largediv" style="
     width: 408px;
     margin: 10px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     font-size: 13px;
     min-height: 50px;
     text-align: justify;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
     box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #CCC;
     border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;">
```

As we can see we have 2 `largediv`s and 4 `smalldiv`s which is dynamically generated yet

**Question:** I want to arrange small and large div in a proper way. As like this picture. fig (1). but they are coming like as fig (2)

As i said I cannot create sub wrappers because they are dynamically and very important serial wise generated...if i make the subwrapper then it cant be in serial wise

**Note:** I can not make another special div to contain `smalldiv` or `largediv` to separate it,  because that small and large div is in a serial wise so we cant put them in a special container and they are dynamic.

In JSFIDDLE -> http://jsfiddle.net/jwy3c3n5/ when you delete the upper most smalldiv then it will work fine but when you add smalldiv on top it goes mad.. i want to fix it and make it proper way at unlimited div

a div will either be largediv or smalldiv, there will could be a variable number of each and can appear in any order. All largediv and smalldiv are contained within wincontainer. Additional markup is not allowed.

Comment: Why is wincontainer using an ordered list (ol) tag?

Comment: @user319940 ohh it doesn't matter if i rename it "div" the result will be same

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with exactly how the code looks and I'm sure you'll get more help.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? If you only need modern browsers (not IE9 or before), then flexbox I would suggest trying out flexbox.

Comment: @Blowski google chrome..

Comment: @user319940 jsfiddle updated

Comment: is a little javascript acceptable?

Comment: @threed yes dear but just solve it

Comment: Take a look at Josh R.'s answer; I updated it with JavaScript.

Comment: I think you need to supply a different jsFiddle. The one you have provided doesn't seem to comply with your requirements. As I understand it (had to dig through answers and comments) your requirements are as follows: a div will either be `largediv` or `smalldiv`, there will could be a variable number of each and can appear in any order. All `largediv` and `smalldiv` are contained within `wincontainer`. Additional markup is not allowed. Is that correct?

Comment: @hungerstar absolutely correct

Comment: @hungerstar solution please//

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option that requires JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var containerTop = $('.container')[0].offsetTop,
        lpos = containerTop,
        rpos = containerTop;
    $('.container > div').each(function(){
        var $el = $(this),
            el = $el[0];
        if($el.hasClass('large')){
            if(lpos < el.offsetTop){
                $el.css('margin-top', (lpos - el.offsetTop) + "px");
            }
            lpos += $el.height();
        }else if($el.hasClass('small')){
            if(rpos < el.offsetTop){
                $el.css('margin-top', (rpos - el.offsetTop) + "px");
            }
            rpos += $el.height();
        }
        
    });
});
```

```css
.container{
    
}
.container > div{
    width:50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position:relative;
}
.container .large{
    height:400px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    position:relative;
}
.container .small{
    height:150px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
    position:relative;
}

.red{background-color:red}
.blue{background-color:blue}
.green{background-color:green}
.yellow{background-color:yellow}
.purple{background-color:purple}
.orange{background-color:orange}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
    
    <div class='large red'></div>
    <div class='small blue'></div>
    <div class='small green'></div>
    <div class='large yellow'></div>
    <div class='small purple'></div>
    <div class='small orange'></div>    
    
</div>
```

note: I think it would be better to use a div for your "wincontainer" than an ordered list.

Comment: As i said I cannot create sub wrappers because they are dynamically and serial wise generated...if i make the subwrapper then it cant be in serial wise..getting me?

Comment: I apologize. I will test something else and revise my answer.

Comment: look at Jsfiddle example in ques you might help me with that

Comment: Okay I revised the answer. Let me know if this is helpful and accomplishes what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this in a similar stituation, but you could set **display:inline-block** on largediv and smalldiv. Maybe that would do it.

Edit: and remove the float attribute. But now that i think about it, depending on the order of the divs, this could not be the best solution.

Comment: i think inline-block is not a solution here.PS -not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the id's to classes on your dynamic divs, and then layout the code to flow in div order.

Your css and html worked really.

See the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jwy3c3n5/2/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftwrapper">
        <div class="large">test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br /></div>
        <div class="large">testtest<br />test<br />test<br />test<br /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightwrapper">
        <div class="small">test</div>
        <div class="small">test</div>
        <div class="small">test</div>
        <div class="small">test</div>
    </div>
</div>


#container {
    width: 500px
}
#rightwrapper {
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
}
#leftwrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
}
.large {
    background: gray;
    margin-bottom:10px;    
}
.small{ 
    background: gray; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: As i said I cannot create sub wrappers because they are dynamically and very important serial wise generated...if i make the subwrapper then it cant be in serial wise..getting me?

Comment: who said anything about creating a sub wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

I created a js-fiddle with the information you provided, plus a small edit on the margin for the large div, and the layout appears to be behaving the way you want it to.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/uaeb0Lmv/

I revised the margins as such:

```
#largediv { 
    margin: 10px 30px 30px; 
}
```

For some reason, the follow-up top margin didn't override the original declaration. Let me know if that works for you. Otherwise, we may need more info on the div contents.

Comment: Andrew..as i said it is dynamically generated so any div which is largediv or smalldiv comes in anytime

Comment: what if i put css like this in your html content?
please try this and look at the results --> 

`
<!-- wincontainer -->
<ul>
<ol class="wincontainer">

    <!-- smalldiv -->
    <div id="smalldiv">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="smalldiv">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="largediv"></div>
    <div id="smalldiv">&nbsp;</div>
     <div id="largediv"></div>
<div id="smalldiv">&nbsp;</div>

    <!-- largediv -->
    <div id="largediv"></div>

    <div id="largediv"></div>
<div id="smalldiv">&nbsp;</div>

</ol>
</ul>`

Answer (score -1):

I understand your problem and i try to solve your problems. You can use this code. It is working.

[Live Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/fmrq9u8n/1/)

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="main">
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>

<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>
<div id="six"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
#main
{
    height:410px;
    width:450px;
    border:5px solid black;
}

#one
{
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:red;
    border:5px solid black;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
#two
{
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:green;
    border:5px solid black;
    margin-top:20px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
#three
{
    height:60px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    border:5px solid black;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    display:table-cell;
    margin-top:-160px;
}

#four
{
    height:60px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:gold;
    border:5px solid black;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    display:table-cell;
    margin-top:-60px;
}

#five
{
    height:60px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:purple;
    border:5px solid black;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    display:table-cell;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:-210px;
}

#six
{
    height:60px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:gray;
    border:5px solid black;
    margin-left:-210px;
    margin-top:140px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: as i said it is dynalically generated so we cant assume which will come first..smalldiv or largediv any div comes in anytime because it is dynamic..
Ps - add your div "one" to last then see it will also become mad :(